# Measure Theory, Content defined over monotonic function

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-functions

Let $\mathcal{I}:=\{[a,b): a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a\leq b\}$ and $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a monotonically increasing function.

Define $\mu:\mathcal{I}\to [0,\infty),\quad \mu([a,b))=F(b)-F(a)$.

Show that $\mu$ is a content.

Proving that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ is easy.

It remains to prove that $\mu$ is finite $\sigma$-additive.
Arguing inductively it is clear that it suffices to prove the result for two pairwise disjoint bounded half open intervalls.

So we have to show that $\mu([a,b)\cup [c,d))=\mu([a,b))+\mu([c,d))$ where $a\leq b<c\leq d$.

The problem I have is to rewrite $[a,b)\cup [c,d)$ as an element of $\mathcal{I}$, as the function $\mu$ only takes bounded half open intervalls as an input, or to find some other workaround.

So how do I get to an expression that $\mu$ can actually map the union of two intervalls to something.

I tried to just "glue" the two intervalls together, so it is an element of $\mathcal{I}$, in the obvious way. But the problem is that this content is not generally translation invariant, as it depends on the values of $F$, so this "glueing" does not work.

Edit: I figured in the mean time that $\mathcal{I}$ is a half ring. Hence closed under union.
The problem remains how to argue that $\mu$ then maps to the desired values.

Comment: What is the definition of a content?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(measure_theory)

Comment: $\mathcal I$ is not closed under unions, since for instance $[0,1)\cup[2,3)$ is not an interval. If I get the definition of a content right, you only need to consider the case where the union of the intervals is an interval itself, and that should be trivial.

Comment: @ViHdzP Oh, silly me. You are absolutlely right. I should have read more carefully... I can assume that the union is in $\mathcal{I}$ and hence an intervall of the desired form... Than it is trivial, as you say. Thanks.